# Spring WebFlux WebClient - How to resolve 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am a newbie to reactive programming and I am using Spring WebFlux's WebClient to make a POST request to the below URL as part of my Spring Boot application to assign an existing quiz to a candidate. I am having trouble understanding what I've done wrong in constructing my WebClient request.

**End-point**

`https://www.flexiquiz.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/quizzes`

In my request body, I need to pass the quiz id that I get from another API (works fine).

```
{
   "quiz_id": ""
}
```

Apart from passing the request body, I am also passing **X-API-KEY** as part of request header.

However, when I tried hitting the end-point, I am getting a **{"message":"400: Bad Request"}** error.

Below is my code.

***QuizRequest.java***

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class QuizRequest {

  @JsonProperty("quiz_id")
  @NotBlank
  private String quizId;

  public QuizRequest(@NotBlank String quizId) {
    this.quizId = quizId;
  }
}
```

***FlexiQuizClient.java***

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class FlexiQuizClient {

  private static final String USER_AGENT = "WebClient for FlexiQuiz";

  private final WebClient webClient;

  @Value("${flexiquiz.baseurl}")
  private String FLEXIQUIZ_API_BASE_URL;

  @Value("${flexiquiz.key}")
  private String FLEXIQUIZ_API_KEY;

  @Autowired
  public FlexiQuizClient() {
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(FLEXIQUIZ_API_BASE_URL)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
        .filter(logRequest())
        .build();
  }

  public String assignQuizToCandidate(String userId, QuizRequest quizRequest) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(webClient.post()
        .uri(FLEXIQUIZ_API_BASE_URL + "/v1/users/" + userId + "/quizzes")
        .header("X-API-KEY", FLEXIQUIZ_API_KEY)
        .body(Mono.just(quizRequest), QuizRequest.class)
        .exchange()
        .block())
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
  }

  private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return (clientRequest, next) -> {
      log.info("Request: {} {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
      clientRequest.headers()
          .forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.info("{}={}", name, value)));
      return next.exchange(clientRequest);
    };
  }
}
```

In my resource class (controller), I am calling the web client method as shown below:

***ResponseResource.java***

```
private String assignQuizToCandidate(String userId, QuizRequest quizRequest)
      throws ParseException {
    log.info("Assigning a quiz based on your skill");
    String message = quizClient.assignQuizToCandidate(userId, quizRequest);
    log.info("message from status: " + message);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(message);
    return (String) json.get("message");
}
```

Inside another method I am calling the above method as shown below.

```
QuizRequest quizRequest = new QuizRequest(openQuiz.get().getQuizId());
String status = assignQuizToCandidate(userId, quizRequest);
```

Below are the logs:

```
2020-05-17 10:20:09.938 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2020-05-17 10:20:09.938 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Handler is being applied: {uri=https://www.flexiquiz.com/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, method=POST}
2020-05-17 10:20:09.939 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443]}}, [request_prepared])
2020-05-17 10:20:09.939 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [1bbedd72] Encoding [QuizRequest(quizId={quizid})]
2020-05-17 10:20:09.941 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443]}}, [request_sent])
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Cache-Control=private, Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8, Server=Microsoft-IIS/10.0, Date=Sun, 17 May 2020 04:50:10 GMT, Content-Length=30]
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443]}}, [response_received])
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1bbedd72] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Received last HTTP packet
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443]}}, [response_completed])
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] onStateChange(POST{uri=/api/v1/users/{userid}/quizzes, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443]}}, [disconnecting])
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Releasing channel
2020-05-17 10:20:10.189 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Channel cleaned, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2020-05-17 10:20:10.190 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x2b404095, L:/192.168.0.106:62197 - R:www.flexiquiz.com/208.117.41.204:443] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 1, cancelled:false, inboundDone: true]
2020-05-17 10:20:10.190 DEBUG 32600 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.core.codec.StringDecoder             : [1bbedd72] Decoded "{"message":"400: Bad Request"}"
2020-05-17 10:20:10.190  INFO 32600 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] i.d.ivrauto.resource.ResponseResource    : message from status: {"message":"400: Bad Request"}
2020-05-17 10:20:10.190  INFO 32600 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] i.d.ivrauto.resource.ResponseResource    : json.get(message): 400: Bad Request
2020-05-17 10:20:10.190  INFO 32600 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2020-05-17 10:20:10.195 DEBUG 32600 --- [nio-8086-exec-6] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
```

Below is the end point I am trying to access.

```
POST: /v1/users/{user_id}/quizzes
```

***Example Request***

```
$ curl https://www.flexiquiz.com/api/v1/users/06e3244f-1381-4da4-aa75-996981b42edb/quizzes 
-H "X-API-KEY: fcb5f59c-2a2f-44a9-8261-33cbfa97be99"
-d quiz_id="1153af46-9580-4672-af78-f23ce2577a14"
```

***Example Response***

```
{                             
    "message": "200: OK"
}
```

Comment: can you please try sending the request without a custom user agent header.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf No, it didn't help. Still get 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Can you post your logs or run your application in debug so we can se the actual request made

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Have edited my question with logs.

Comment: What does your server endpoint look like? you've provided the client code but not the server method.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Added sample request and response to my question.

Comment: Your `curl` command is a **FORM** post by default, but the `body()` in  `assignQuizToCandidate` serialized into `application/json`. They are different content type.

Comment: @Hantsy but I am constructing POST request what is that I need to do now? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is probably that you are sending the data in the wrong format. You are posting data in the body in the `application/json` format.

But if you look in the request it is made using the `-d` flag in `curl`.

From the curl documentation:

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified  data  in  a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a
>          browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause
>          curl  to  pass  the  data  to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>          Compare to -F, --form.

Which basically means that you need to send the data in `FORM` format.

The Webflux documentation tells how to send the data as a form request.

[Webflux Send FormData](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body-form)

So your code should look like something (sort of):

```
public QuizResponse assignQuizToCandidate(String userId, String quizId) {

    final MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("quiz_id", quizId);

    return webClient.post()
        .uri(FLEXIQUIZ_API_BASE_URL + "/v1/users/" + userId + "/quizzes")
        .header("X-API-KEY", FLEXIQUIZ_API_KEY)
        .bodyValue(formData)
        .retrive()
        .bodyToMono(QuizResponse.class)
        .block();
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct man! I am going to accept your answer. Also, I will add my solution based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ThomasAndolf answer here is what I had to do.

```
public String assignQuizToCandidate(String userId, String quizId) {
    final MultiValueMap<String, String> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    data.add("quiz_id", quizId);

    return webClient.post()
        .uri(FLEXIQUIZ_API_BASE_URL + "/v1/users/" + userId + "/quizzes")
        .header("X-API-KEY", FLEXIQUIZ_API_KEY)
        .bodyValue(data)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
  }
```

I took the output as a String since the response only contains a string with the following message:
`{"message": "200: OK"}`